# IPN handling with paypal-recurring gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal-ipn

I have tried to figure out this response back to PayPal for a while and it drives me nuts. Somewhere I need to send it back to stop PayPal from re-sending the IPN. This is my code for the IPN listener so far, how do I send the IPN response? Just doing ppr.valid? creates a VERIFIED response but the IPN messages keep coming so I guess that doesn't count as an IPN response. The valid? line always fails as well as it can't find the email and seller_id, which I also need to put somewhere (this stuff needs documentation). See gem documentation here: https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring

```
def ipn
  subscription = Subscription.where(:email => params[:payer_email], :status => "Active").last
  if subscription
    ppr = PayPal::Recurring::Notification.new(params)

    PaymentsNotification.create!(:params => params.to_json, :status => params[:payment_status], :transaction_id => params[:txn_id])

    if ppr.valid? && (ppr.express_checkout? || ppr.recurring_payment?)
       #business logic
    end
end
```

I ended up with this code:

```
def ipn
subscription = Subscription.where(:email => params[:payer_email], :status => "Active").last
if subscription
  PaymentsNotification.create!(:params => params.to_json.gsub("\"", "'"), :status => params[:payment_status], :transaction_id => params[:txn_id])
  ppr = PayPal::Recurring::Notification.new(params)
  ppr.response #send back the response to confirm IPN, stops further IPN notifications from being sent out
  if ppr.verified? && ppr.completed?
    if ppr.express_checkout? || ppr.recurring_payment?
      #do stuff here
    end
  else
    #raise response.errors.inspect
  end
end
render :nothing => true
```

end

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?